# Inquiry about hosting site with Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am considering using Google to host a basic social media app.  I would like to upload my own php files and use their Google Cloud SQL Database.  My question may be very simple, what is the name of the Google service that would let me host a dynamic site?

Comment: Google Cloud has several options. LAMP. Firebase etc... https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/php

you can use AppEngine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xuf3J6SKVV0&list=PLIivdWyY5sqIQ4_5PwyyXZVdsXr3wYhip

also watch this video for quick intro